# Error in running spark application

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop-yarn

I have a very simple Spark application that I run on a pre-built Spark 1.4.1 however I gt a strange error message as follows

```bash
 Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/protobuf/ServiceException
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine.<clinit>(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:69)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:270)
    at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClassByNameOrNull(Configuration.java:1659)
    at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClassByName(Configuration.java:1624)
    at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClass(Configuration.java:1718)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC.getProtocolEngine(RPC.java:203)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC.getProtocolProxy(RPC.java:537)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.NameNodeProxies.createNNProxyWithClientProtocol(NameNodeProxies.java:328)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.NameNodeProxies.createNonHAProxy(NameNodeProxies.java:235)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.NameNodeProxies.createProxy(NameNodeProxies.java:139)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.<init>(DFSClient.java:510)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.<init>(DFSClient.java:453)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem.initialize(DistributedFileSystem.java:136)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.createFileSystem(FileSystem.java:2433)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.access$200(FileSystem.java:88)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.getInternal(FileSystem.java:2467)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.get(FileSystem.java:2449)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(FileSystem.java:367)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(FileSystem.java:166)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobConf.getWorkingDirectory(JobConf.java:653)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileInputFormat.setInputPaths(FileInputFormat.java:389)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileInputFormat.setInputPaths(FileInputFormat.java:362)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$hadoopFile$1$$anonfun$32.apply(SparkContext.scala:980)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$hadoopFile$1$$anonfun$32.apply(SparkContext.scala:980)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.HadoopRDD$$anonfun$getJobConf$6.apply(HadoopRDD.scala:176)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.HadoopRDD$$anonfun$getJobConf$6.apply(HadoopRDD.scala:176)
    at scala.Option.map(Option.scala:145)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.HadoopRDD.getJobConf(HadoopRDD.scala:176)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.HadoopRDD.getPartitions(HadoopRDD.scala:200)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:219)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:217)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:120)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.partitions(RDD.scala:217)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.getPartitions(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:32)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:219)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:217)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:120)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.partitions(RDD.scala:217)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.getPartitions(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:32)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:219)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:217)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:120)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.partitions(RDD.scala:217)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.getPartitions(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:32)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:219)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:217)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:120)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.partitions(RDD.scala:217)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.getPartitions(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:32)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:219)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$partitions$2.apply(RDD.scala:217)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:120)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.partitions(RDD.scala:217)
    at org.apache.spark.Partitioner$.defaultPartitioner(Partitioner.scala:65)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions$$anonfun$reduceByKey$3.apply(PairRDDFunctions.scala:290)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions$$anonfun$reduceByKey$3.apply(PairRDDFunctions.scala:290)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:147)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:108)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:286)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.PairRDDFunctions.reduceByKey(PairRDDFunctions.scala:289)
    at org.apache.spark.mllib.feature.Word2Vec.learnVocab(Word2Vec.scala:149)
    at org.apache.spark.mllib.feature.Word2Vec.fit(Word2Vec.scala:267)
    at SimpleApp$.main(simpleApp.scala:12)
    at SimpleApp.main(simpleApp.scala)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:665
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:170)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:193)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:112)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.protobuf.ServiceException
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
```

I tried to add `protobuf-java-2.0.3.jar` to my classpath but it didn't help. An idea on what the problem can be?

Comment: can you update with the command you've used to add the missing jar?

Comment: Could you explain exactly what you mean, I didn't get it.